# Correct link to the Teachers' Lounge

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface, moderator-tools, teachers-lounge

It's not a big bug, but can we fix the UI error to no longer show the recent activities from the old Teachers' Lounge chat room please, which is a lot quieter than the new room too, and point to the correct one.

The bug appeared in my moderator dashboard.

See the edited printscreen;

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would close this request as the room was renamed today to **INACTIVE Teachers' Lounge**. (I seen Em C's comment too late, but it was renamed again today, so I happened to see the change (2020-05-27))

It's now easy to spot the correct room, no more error possible.

*nb, I agree I should have filled my bug report as a suggestion for a name change instead.*

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The lower box where you see "102 people chatting" is not a *link to the Teachers' Lounge* per se: it shows **recently active private chatrooms on chat.SE**. Different mods are going to see different things there. If your own site mod room has been active recently, you'll see that; otherwise, you'll see some selection of private rooms that are visible to mods from across the whole SE network, like the unparented TL room.

**I don't think this should be changed.** It's often useful to see a quick link to your own site's private mod room in that sidebar, instead of a link to one specific mod room (new-TL) on the other chat server, which is already linked from elsewhere in the sidebar anyway.

Comment: The point is that the old TL link shouldn't be showing up at all, since it's been temporarily switched over to the new room on chat.Meta.

Comment: @Mithical It's a recently-active private chatroom on the chat.SE server. Why shouldn't it be showing up?

Comment: Because people shouldn't be using it. If it's showing up, then people are more likely to use it.

Comment: @Mithical I'd oppose anything which prevents me from seeing that sidebar entry with recently-active private chatrooms on the chat.SE server. It's a quick way both to see new activity in my own site's mod room (which I don't check every day as it's usually inactive) and to keep up on anything interesting going on in network-wide mod rooms. I'd also be against disallowing frozen chatrooms from appearing there, since mod chatrooms frequently freeze for inactivity and mods don't bother unfreezing them.

Comment: My view is that room specifically shouldn't be there. I followed that link to see a room with over 20 peoples inside it, if I would be a new mod, how I know I shouldnt be there ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 So post a message there stating they're in the wrong room with a link to the new room and pin it. Pin it every 2 weeks again till nobody shows up.

Comment: @Mast well, shog did it in the past for some time, and yet today I'am here to state a room that is far from beeing empty. Renaming the room with an archive in the name could be an option, but having two admin room with the same name is misleading IMO

Comment: @yagmoth555 I think the response to your question would've been different had you suggested a name change instead of filing this as a bug.

Comment: @yagmoth555 The room had been renamed to add "(inactive)", when we first switched to the meta chatroom. Since it's on regular chat you could always edit it again and/or update the description to include a link to meta. [See here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=room+topic+changed&room=4) for the history.

Answer (score 7):

The solution to this problem is simple: **stop using the old chatroom**. What you see there are two of the most recent active private chatrooms on the chat server of that site (the new Teachers' Lounge is on the Meta chat server). If nobody posts a message, the old room will never appear in that widget anymore.

Comment: I stopped using it, like 6 month ago, and used the new room. As the old room was told to no longer use. Kinda why it appeared to me as a bug. It's a staff that posted inside it

Comment: It's mostly moderators who posted there recently (though there is a reply from staff from last Friday).